# jQuery conditionally add/remove onclick and onserverclick attributes

Tags: jquery

I am working on a c# project.

I have an anchor tag and I want to add/remove onlick and onserverclick attributes based on some condition.

**Design:-**

```
<a class="btnSelected" href="#" name="Platinum" onclick="if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to change the plan?')) return false;" onserverclick="UpdatePackage_Click" runat="server">upgrade</a>
```

**jQuery:-**

```
 if ($("#" + '<%= hdnPackType.ClientID %>').val() != $("#" + '<%= hdnOrigionalPackType.ClientID %>').val()) {         
        $('a.btnSelected').html('select').attr("onclick", "if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to change the plan?')) return false;");
        }
        else {
            $('a.btnSelected').html('<i class="fa fa-check mr-10"></i>selected').removeAttr('onclick').removeAttr('href');
        }
```

Comment: you can't add attributes to a text element

Comment: should i go for a button?

Comment: i don't know what you are trying to do

Comment: i want to add/remove onclick and onserverclick attributes on a anchor/button..

Answer (score 0):

Using data attributes is your need. I made an example for you.

```
<div class="row text-center">
<div class="col-md-4">
    plan 1 
    <button class="btn btn-info btnSelect" data-plan="1">select</button>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    plan 2
    <button class="btn btn-info btnSelect" data-plan="2">select</button>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    plan 3
    <button class="btn btn-info btnSelect" data-plan="3">select</button>
</div>
```

```
$(".btnSelect").on("click", function() {
    $(".btnSelect").removeClass("btn-success");
    $(this).addClass("selected").addClass("btn-success").removeClass("btn-info");   
    $("#result").text("Plan " + $(this).attr("data-plan") + " selected");
});
```

[codepen demo](http://codepen.io/airsakarya/pen/zNMxNb?editors=1010)